# How to effectively implement GROUP BY combination of columns in HiveQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, combinations, hiveql

For example, I have the following table named Roll:

```
ID    Name    Address
---------------------
01    Lily    NewYork
02    Lucy    NewYork
03    Lucy    NewYork
```

and I want to get COUNT(1) GROUP BY combination of column Name and Address:

```
SELECT Name, Address, COUNT(1) FROM Roll GROUP BY Name, Address
+
SELECT Name, COUNT(1) FROM Roll GROUP BY Name
+
SELEC Address, COUNT(1) FROM Roll GROUP BY Address
+
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Roll
```

The following SQL can realize my idea and '##' represents 'GROUP BY NONE':

```
SELECT Name, Address, COUNT(1) FROM (
SELECT Name, Address FROM Roll
UNION ALL
SELECT '##', Address FROM Roll
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, '##' FROM Roll
UNION ALL
SELECT '##', '##' FROM Roll) t
GROUP by Name, Address;
```

The result:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| Name | Address | COUNT(1) |
+------+---------+----------+
| ##   | ##      |        3 |
| ##   | NewYork |        3 |
| Lily | ##      |        1 |
| Lily | NewYork |        1 |
| Lucy | ##      |        2 |
| Lucy | NewYork |        2 |
+------+---------+----------+
```

Is the more efficient way to implement it except the above one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for sub-totals? if so that can be achieved with grouping sets and cube/rollup. [check this wiki about grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Enhanced+Aggregation,+Cube,+Grouping+and+Rollup)

Comment: Thanks, it's almost what I'm looking for. What I'm still concerned about is the efficiency. We'll have a test to compare between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT coalesce(Name,"##"), coalesce(Address,"##"), count(1)
FROM ROLL
GROUP BY Name, Address with cube;
```

I guess this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I've pasted the output of the query.

Comment: ok.. but what actually you need?? If just count of all distinct name and address is what you look for.., then the query that I have pasted will be suffice.. But Still I didn't get the intent behind adding '##' in your query